# Spotify Api in Php

Tags: php, api, spotify

I want to add currently listening spotify track on my website. For getting currently playing track on spotify with using spotify api. The library I used is [jwilsons library](https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php).

I use this code:

```
    <?php  
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    $session = new SpotifyWebAPI\Session(
        'CLIENT_ID',
        'CLIENT_SECRET',
        'REDIRECT_URI'
    );
    $options = [
        'scope' => [
            'playlist-read-private',
            'user-read-private',
            'user-read-playback-state'
        ],
    ];
    if(empty($_GET)){              
        header('Location: ' . $session->getAuthorizeUrl($options));
    }else{                               


    // Request a access token using the code from Spotify
    $session->requestAccessToken($_GET['code']);

    $accessToken = $session->getAccessToken();

    // Store the access and refresh tokens somewhere. In a database for example.

    echo "<a href=my_spot.php>refresh page</a><br>"; 
    $api = new SpotifyWebAPI\SpotifyWebAPI();
    $api->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    // It's now possible to request data about the currently authenticated user
    $api->getMyCurrentTrack(null);

         echo "ad soyad=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->item->album->artists[0]->name;//->spotify;
         echo "<br>id=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->item->album->artists[0]->id;
         echo "<br>url=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->item->external_urls->spotify;
         echo "<br>image=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->item->album->images[0]->url;
         echo "<br>sure=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->item->duration_ms;
         echo "<br>calinan sure=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->progress_ms;
         echo "<br>album=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->item->album->name;
         echo "<br>Şarkı=".$api->getLastResponse()["body"]->item->name;
    } 
  ?>
```

Everything works perfect but every time when i run this code IT need authoritize. And open this screen:

[image]

I want to only get song name and album name. Is there a simply way to get what i need?

Comment: you need to store the access token for future use. why do you get one for every reload?

Comment: What happen on first visitors? they still need to redirect spotify authorizite page and ask user for permission. I dont want to do that. Next step is second time they visit i can use that access token code. But I am looking for no ask permission for first time. thats the reason i didnt store the access token.

Comment: You cannot access the API without token, it woudl be a huge security problem if you could. So people have to authorise your app to make it work.